# Why in the U.S. sometimes the doughnut is called sinker?

Tags: food

Why in the U.S. sometimes the doughnut is called sinker? I'm not familiar with U.S.'s food or slang.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the word, or looking at the [Wikipedia page for the word _sinker_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinker)? That should give you your answer. It's the same reason one of the largest chains of doughnut shops is called _Dunkin’_ Donuts.

Comment: I always figured it had to do with what a cheap donut did once it got inside your stomach.

Comment: It's quite interesting that one of the most common Chinese ways of eating a [youtiao (fried doughstick)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youtiao),  a traditional breakfast item is dipping or sinking it into [doujiang (soy milk)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doujiang), which is also very common breakfast item.

Comment: BTW, by comparison, I always felt that a typical US donut is too sweet and too firm to eat -- maybe it was me not knowing it is supposed to be submerged into coffee.

Comment: There are many types of doughnuts in the US.  Some of which are so light and airy that they just melt in your mouth.  These are typically raised doughnuts.  Cake doughnuts are denser although they vary widely on just how dense (and moist) they are.